# Rest API not working in Postman with JSON Data

Tags: java, mysql, json, hibernate, rest

I  am integrating Rest with hibernate and MySQL, my hibernate is working fine but API is not working on postman.

I require my API to provide a JSON object.

DAO Class

```
package com.practice.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import com.practice.bean.User;
import com.practice.entity.UserEntity;
import com.practice.resources.HibernateUtility;

public class UserDAO {
    public List<User> showAllUsers() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        Session session = null;
        List<User> userResult = new ArrayList<>();

        sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.createSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Query q1 = session.createQuery("FROM UserEntity");

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<UserEntity> u1 =(List<UserEntity>) q1.list();
        for (UserEntity ue : u1) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setUserId(ue.getUserId());
            user.setUserEmail(ue.getUserEmail());
            user.setUserName(ue.getUserName());
            user.setUserpassword(ue.getUserpassword());
            userResult.add(user);
        }
        return userResult;
    }
}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
   id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <display-name>User Management</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.practice.api</param-value>
         </init-param>
      </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Jersey RESTful Application</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

API

```
package com.practice.api;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.practice.bean.User;
import com.practice.dao.UserDAO;

@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService {
    UserDAO user = new UserDAO();

    @GET
    @Path("/users")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getUsers() {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<User> l1 = new ArrayList<User>();
        l1 = user.showAllUsers();
        return gson.toJson(l1);
    }
}
```

Updated:
Error in postman

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.36 - Error report</title>
        <style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 404 - /Practice/rest/UserService</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Status report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>/Practice/rest/UserService</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The requested resource is not available.</u>
        </p>
        <hr class="line">
        <h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.36</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What happens when you make a GET request to `whatever/UserService/users`?

Comment: please check the updated code for errors

Comment: You're getting a 404 response which means what you're looking for cannot be found. This could indicate that you're sending a request to the wrong URL.

Comment: i have rechecked the url and it seems to be perfectly fine, can you suggest something else?

Comment: Maybe the application isn't running. If it is... is it running on localhost? Are you sending a request to the right port? e.g. `http://localhost:8080/api/UserService/users`

Comment: my hibernate code is working perfectly, but when i test my rest api with `http://localhost:8080/Practice/rest/UserService/users` it gives a 404 error

Comment: Is your program listening for requests on port 8080?

Comment: yes that's correct.

Comment: Is it definitely running?

Comment: Show us the HTTP request you made. I think you may have a mistake in it.

Comment: yes i suppose because when i run http://localhost:8080/ my tomcat home page opens up.

Comment: maybe this link can give you my complete code 'https://github.com/yashikgulati/practice.git'

Comment: ... This is all compiled...

Comment: have you checked server log while deploying the application?

Comment: Thank you Brandon it worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem instead of having bunch of codes?

Answer (score 0):

the error message say :
*HTTP Status 404 - /Practice/rest/UserService*
which means that you forgot to add /users

try this GET : /Practice/rest/UserService/**users**